# Convert array into a encrypted token with php

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to make Rest Service with PHP. I need to encrypt user details array into encrypted token and need to decrypt. Is there any simple framework for PHP rest service with angular js.

Comment: JWT (JSON Web tokens)

Comment: give us some context for your requirement. what do you do with the token? Where does the data get encrypted? decrypted?

Comment: @brianlmerritt JSON Web tokens are not encrypted by default. They are just base64 encoded and signed.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes I need encrypted tokens for API service.  Any example tutorials are available? After logging by the user the server will encrypt the user information array into a token. This token will send to the server for every request by the client.

Comment: Why not use hashing? The info doesn't need to be decrypted, since the server already knows the user information. The rest of the user's request can be encryped by SSL (over https).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume, for an instant, that you have an array of data like this:

```
<?php
    $userDataArray  = [
        'username'      => "user101",
        'password'      => "letMeIn101",
        'email'         => "user101@domain.com",
        'emailPass'     => "letMeIn101Again",
        'accountNr'     => "CB-1087-4789-US-CA-1",
        'accountKey'    => '${6@/A-p*h154a',
        'swiftKey'      => '@%o98-eZ6_ii',
    ];
```

> And you would like to "2-way-encrypt" it in PHP so as to use it in  another Application; You could use openssl_encrypt() and openssl_decrypt() like so:

```
<?php
    // FIRST CONVERT THE $userDataArray INTO JSON STRING
    $userDataJSON   = json_encode($userDataArray);

    // NEXT CREATE A PASSWORD AND METHOD TO USE FOR ENCRYPTION...
    $pass           = 'suDoLetMeIn';
    $method         = 'aes-128-cbc';
    $initVector     = "0123456789012345";    // MUST BE 16 BYTES LONG...

    // NOW ENCRYPT THE DATA...
    $encrypted      = openssl_encrypt($userDataJSON, $method, $pass, false, $initVector);

    // TRY DUMPING THE ENCRYPTED DATA TO SEE WHAT YOU GET
    var_dump($encrypted);

    // ATTEMPT TO DECRYPT THE DATA
    $decrypted      = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $pass, false, $initVector);

    // AGAIN TRY DUMPING THE DECRYPTED DATA TO SEE WHAT YOU GET
    // REMEMBER TO DECODE IT SINCE IT WAS JSON-ENCODED IN THE FIRST PLACE...
    var_dump($decrypted);
    var_dump(json_decode($decrypted));
```

> The var_dumps above would respectively produce something like::

```
    string 'CwwYkIb319h+xSRkv+uV7PaAJ52ouwGWn0pA/cVQmVtzzmPMzBsH9iOWelNmiNUSeaT93624KoTAkFyXnlw3jWAzW8ekO8x+sKMnhZuXFiaIHDaEsrhIpydHLMhwtgwDo3g2x1vY+9hGuqAm2P+eh925NmKCFcuDgZgDBuoaEGV8CXqPBVRWV8gNrw70s9JPmiXcntALM9TtqGLpRpVBjCBP/o0ScliHCehH1+9eKQyg5zkzJApE7jov/hbluzpF2pDfZ7QQpcOVuqqcCyRPlQ==' (length=280)

    string '{"username":"user101","password":"letMeIn101","email":"user101@domain.com","emailPass":"letMeIn101Again","accountNr":"CB-1087-4789-US-CA-1","accountKey":"${6@\/A-p*h154a","swiftKey":"@%o98-eZ6_ii"}' (length=197)

    object(stdClass)[8]
      public 'username' => string 'user101' (length=7)
      public 'password' => string 'letMeIn101' (length=10)
      public 'email' => string 'user101@domain.com' (length=18)
      public 'emailPass' => string 'letMeIn101Again' (length=15)
      public 'accountNr' => string 'CB-1087-4789-US-CA-1' (length=20)
      public 'accountKey' => string '${6@/A-p*h154a' (length=14)
      public 'swiftKey' => string '@%o98-eZ6_ii' (length=12)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it secured?

Answer (score 0):

A fully RESTful server implementation for CodeIgniter using one library, one config file and one controller.

Check more about authentication here....https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#authentication